# Incomplete download using saveURI()

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, firefox-addon

So I'm trying to download a PDF file with this link:
http://www.freecybers.com/components/com_flexpaper/assets/zine/php/services/simpleview.php?doc=regus.pdf

Here's my code:

```
function downPdf() {
    linkPdf = getPdfLink();
    var webBrowserPersist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
    var localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    localFile.initWithPath("D:\\file.pdf")
    var iOService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
    link = iOService.newURI(linkPdf, null, null);
    webBrowserPersist.saveURI(link, null, null, null, null, localFile, null);  
}
```

The PDF size is 114 KB but download always stops at 108 KB so the file is corrupted. Does anybody know what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Tried to mess with persists flags, I added:

```
 webBrowserPersist.persistFlags = webBrowserPersist.PERSIST_FLAGS_AUTODETECT_APPLY_CONVERSION;
```

before using saveURI(). Looks like it was an encoding issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution! I looked into it and I was stumped. Really appreciate the solution.